# How to redirect http://mysite/css/ to http://server1.mysite.com/css?

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess, url-rewriting

How can i redirect all requests passed to

```
http://mysite.com/css
```

to
`http://otherserver.otherserver.com/css` ?

User typing

```
http://mysite.com/css/somefile.css
```

and go redirect to

```
http://otherserver.otherserver/css/comefile.css
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I found it :)

```
RewriteRule ^css(.*)$ http://www.someserver.com/css$1 [L,R=301]
```